# PySpark on Linux with pycharm - first exception error

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I am trying to run my first PySpark script on a Linux VM I configured. The error message I have is `KeyError: SPARK_HOME` when I run the following:

```
from os import environ
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

I momentarily made this error go away by running `export SPARK_HOME=~/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7`. I then ran into a new error `error=2, No such file or directory`. Searching took me to this page:https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Tutorial-Install-Configure-iPython-and-create-run-PySpark/ta-p/246400. I then ran `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=~/python3*`. This brings me back to experiencing the `KeyError: SPARK_HOME` error.

Honestly, I'm stumbling through this, because it's my first time configuring Spark, and using PySpark. I still don't quite understand the ins-and-outs of pycharm, as well.

I expect to be able to run the following basic sample script on this page: https://medium.com/parrot-prediction/integrating-apache-spark-2-0-with-pycharm-ce-522a6784886f with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package called findspark  [here](https://github.com/minrk/findspark)

or you may use below code to set path if not found in environment

```
import os
if 'SPARK_HOME' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = 'full_path_to_spark_root'
```

[code continues]

Comment: I fixed the path using the above. I could not however use the findspark method (received an error that the module could not be found). After I rerun the original script I provided, I still get the `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:` error.